# The scroll buttons in my script wont work

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

`<!DOCTYPE html>

```
    Sideways Scrolling List
    
        ul {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            overflow-x: scroll;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        li {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            background: #ccc;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        button {
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
            background: #444;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sideways Scrolling List</h1>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Scrolling List of Items</title>

            <script>
                function ScrollLeft() {
                    var list = document.getElementById("list");
                    list.scrollBy(10, 0);
                }

                function ScrollRight() {
                    var list = document.getElementById("list");
                    list.scrollBy(-10, 0);
                }
            </script>

            <style>
                .scroll-container {
                    overflow: auto;
                    white-space: nowrap;
                    background-color: #f5f5f5;
                    padding: 15px;
                    border-radius: 10px;
                }
                .scroll-list {
                    display: inline-block;
                    list-style-type: none;
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    font-size: 1.2em;
                    color: #444;
                }
                .scroll-list li {
                    display: inline-block;
                    padding: 10px 20px;
                    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    border-radius: 10px;
                    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
                }
                .scroll-list li:hover {
                    background-color: #f5f5f5;
                    transform: scale(1.1);
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="scroll-container">
                <ul class="scroll-list" id="list">
                    <li>Item 16</li>
                    <li>Item 17</li>
                    <li>Item 18</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                    <li>Item 19</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <button onclick="scrollLeft()">Scroll Left</button>
            <button onclick="scrollRight()">Scroll Right</button>

            <script>
                function scrollLeft() {
                    document.querySelector("ul").scrollLeft = 0;
                }
                function scrollRight() {
                    document.querySelector("ul").scrollLeft = document.querySelector("ul").scrollWidth;
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
</body>
```

`

scroll left and right buttons dont work, ive tried using this, window.scrollBy(), ___.scrollLeft and literally nothing works

I expected my sideways list too move left and right onclick

any help as too why this doesnt work would be appreciated, also if there are any methods that do this that are supported by most/all browsers that would be nice, than you

Comment: bruh why did i format this so ass, mb

Answer (score 0):

EDIT ::
I do not know why but the following works ; and i fixed some html "bad practices" ( i noticed there were two html tags in the previous answer i posted ), and it works with the 'ul' tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>Scrolling List of Items</title>
    <style>    
        ul {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                overflow-x: scroll;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

            li {
                list-style: none;
                padding: 10px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                background: #ccc;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            button {
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 10px;
                background: #444;
                color: #fff;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
    </style>
    <script>
        
        function scrollLeftenant() {
            document.querySelector("ul").scrollLeft = 0;
        }

        function scrollRight() {
            document.querySelector("ul").scrollLeft = document.querySelector("ul").scrollWidth;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sideways Scrolling List</h1>
    <div class="scroll-container">
        <ul class="scroll-list" id="list">
            <li>Item 16</li>
            <li>Item 17</li>
            <li>Item 18</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
            <li>Item 19</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button onclick="scrollLeftenant()">Scroll Left</button>
    <button onclick="scrollRight()">Scroll Right</button>

</body>
</html>
```

i had to rename the function from scrollLeft to scrollLeftenant, well the exact name does not matter as long as it is not scrollLeft, it will work, this is probably due to "scrollLeft" probably being used somewhere internally by javascript or something else is overriding it, sooo dont use the name "scrollLeft" for your function names or varibles

Comment: I cant seem too get this too work outside of the stack overflow environment tho, because. I tried another piece of code in an online html complier and it sort of worked there but not in either browser

Comment: it would be helpful if you would state the online compilers so that i go and test them, but i took a look at the code and noticed some "bad practices" so i have edited my answer, especially the code snippet, oh and it works with using "ul" tags now, so you initially had the right idea.

Comment: ah yh mb, I used this website: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_html_compiler

Comment: works for me https://onlinegdb.com/hJfQLhggV